# How to sort table as per column value using Angular.js

Tags: html, angularjs

I need to sort table as per multiple column vlaue using Angular.js. I am explaining my code below.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" id="dataTable" >
                    <colgroup>
                    <col class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
                    <col class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
                    <col class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
                    <col class="col-md-2 col-sm-3">
                    <col class="col-md-2 col-sm-3">
                    </colgroup>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Sl. No</th>
                            <th>City name</th>
                            <th>Pincode</th>
                            <th>T-Factor</th>
                            <th>Edit</th>
                            <th>Remove</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="detailsstockid">
                        <tr ng-repeat="usr in objPincodeData " ng-if="objPincodeData.length > 0">
                            <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
                            <td>{{usr.city_name}}</td>
                            <td>{{usr.pincode}}</td>
                            <td>{{usr.t_factor}}</td>
                            <td><a ui-sref='app.settings.tariff.pincode'><input type='button' class='btn btn-xs btn-green' value='Edit' ng-click="editPincodeData(usr.id);"></a></td>
                            <td ng-if="usr.pincode !=0"><a ui-sref='app.settings.tariff.pincode'><input type='button' class='btn btn-xs btn-red' value='Remove' ng-click="deletePincodeData(usr.id);" ></a></td>
                            <td ng-if="usr.pincode==0">NA</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr ng-if="objPincodeData.length == 0">
                            <td colspan="4">
                                <center>
                                  <p><b>No Record Found</b>
                                  </p>
                               </center>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Here I need to sort table as per `city name and pincode` value. Here I need to sort table as per `city name` in alphabetically order and if `pincode=0` will come first.

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular's [`orderBy`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) in order to achieve that.

You need to add a propertyName parameter (that you will change on column click) that will hold the column name and reverse - boolean value, and then use it within your ng-repeat directive.

Something like that:
    ng-repeat="usr in objPincodeData | orderBy:propertyName:reverse"

Checkout the [example from the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy#changing-parameters-dynamically)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ng-repeat="usr in objPincodeData | orderBy:['city_name','pincode']"
```